# OpenMp and Shared Memory definition

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

According to the [OpenMP web site](http://openmp.org/wp/) OpenMp is *"the de-facto standard for parallel programming on shared memory systems"* According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) "*Using memory for communication inside a single program, for example among its multiple threads, is generally not referred to as shared memory.*"

What is wrong here ? Is it the "generally" term ? 
OpenMp is really just creating threads "sharing memory" through a single same virtual adress space, isn't it ?

Moreover, I guess OpenMP is able to run on NUMA architectures where all the memory can be addressed by all the processors, but with some increased memory access time when threads sharing data, are assigned to cores accessing to different memories at different access time. Is this true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm redacting a full-fledged answer here to try to answer further questions asked as comments to lucas1024's answer.

**On the meaning of "shared memory"**

On the one hand, you have the software-oriented (i.e. OS-oriented) meaning of shared-memory: a way to enable different processes to access the same chunk of memory (i.e. to relax the usual OS constraint that a given process should not be able to tamper with other processes' memory). As stated in the wikipedia page, the POSIX shared memory API is one implementation of such a facility. In this acception, it does not make much sense to speak of threads (an OS might well provide shared memory without even providing threads).

On the other hand, you have the hardware-oriented meaning of "shared-memory": an hardware configuration where all CPUs have access to the same piece of RAM.

**On the meaning of "thread"**

Now we have to disambiguate another term: "thread". An OS might provide a way to have multiple concurrent execution flows within a process. POSIX threads are an implementation of such a feature.

However, the OpenMP specification has its own definitions:

> **thread:** An execution entity with a stack and associated static memory, called
>   threadprivate memory.
>
> **OpenMP thread:** A thread that is managed by the OpenMP runtime system.

Such definitions fit nicely with the definition of e.g. POSIX threads, and most OpenMP implementations indeed use POSIX threads to create OpenMP threads. But you might imagine OpenMP implementations on top of OSes which do not provide POSIX threads or equivalent features. Such OpenMP implementations would have to internally manage execution flows, which is difficult enough but entirely doable. Alternatively, they might map OpenMP threads to OS processes and use some kind of "shared memory" feature (in the OS sense) to enable them sharing memory (though I don't know of any OpenMP implementation doing this).

In the end, the only constraint you have for an OpenMP implementation is that all CPUs should have a way to share access to the same central memory. That is to say OpenMP programs should run on "shared memory" systems in the hardware sense. However, OpenMP threads do not necessarily have to be POSIX threads of the same OS process.

Answer (score 2):

A "shared memory system" is simply a system where multiple cores or CPUs are accessing a single pool of memory through a local bus. So the OpenMP site is correct.
Communicating between threads in a program is not done using "shared memory" - instead the term typically refers to communication between processes on the same machine through memory. So the Wikipedia entry is not in contradiction and it, in fact, points out the difference in terminology between hardware and software.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still don't really get the point about the link between OpenMP and shared memory systems (I guess the OpenMP website refers here to hardware shared memory). Because as you said, Communicating between threads in a program is not done using "shared memory" and because OpenMP is just hiding threads to the programmer, something sounds strange ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva OpenMP specifies this because it can **only** be used on shared memory systems (as opposed to distributed memory systems, which are supported by other parallelization toolsets like MPI). It's very important for potential future users to know that, since it will restrict their ability to run their code on clusters for example. Since OpenMP hides practical implementation details, it doesn't tell you about the way threads communicate.

Comment: @Francesco, I agree that OpenMP can't be used on a cluster. But the reason for that is not related to shared memory vs distributed memory but simply to the fact that OpenMP is an abstraction over threads, and because threads are limited to the surrounding process boundaries. Thus OPenMP can only be used inside a GIVEN PROCESS, is it true ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva this would be too long to fit in a comment. Please see my answer.